# How to use justify alignment in longtabu without affecting the table?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, longtabu

I am using the following code to generate a table..

```
    \begin{longtabu} to \linewidth{@{}XX[6]X[2,c]X[1.5,c]@{}} %{X[1,c]X[4,l]X[1,c]X[l,c]}

\rowcolor{brown!50!black} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{   \color{white} Completed projects (Inter-institutional collaborative projects)}\\
\rowcolor{brown!50!black}    \color{white}  Funding Agency&     \color{white}Title of Project &         \color{white}   Amount\newline (in \rupee)   &      \color{white} Year of sanctioned\newline(Duration)            \\                           
 DST
 &  Genomic variation analysis and gene expression profiling of human dosha prakriti based on principals of ayurveda.                                                &     8,64,000 &March 2007\newline  3 Years
            \\
Intel corporate technology group & Mobile monitoring solutions to improve health outcomes in non-communicable diseases – systematic review. &  2,35,000 &2007\newline  3 Years\\
 ICMR &Aetiology of Acute Encephalitis Syndrome (AES) in India and Establishment of ICMR sample banks of AES cases” – a multisite prospective initiative &  1,04,76,449
 & March 2011\newline 3 Years \\
ICMR &  Molecular epidemiology of rotavirus diarrhea in children under five in Southwest India- A hospital and laboratory based study &  38,75,688 & March 2012\newline 3 Years\\

\end{longtabu}
```

The output is the following.

[image]

### Why the corner is not covered completely?

With the code     `\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth {X[1,c]X[4,l]X[1,c]X[l,c]}` I didnt get this problem.

I am getting this issue after replacing this command by     `\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth{@{}XX[6]X[2,c]X[1.5,c]@{}} %{X[1,c]X[4,l]X[1,c]X[l,c]}`

to justify the column in the table.

### How to getrid off this? Is there a way to justify the  cells without encountering these type of problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

For this you need to make small changes in used `\multicolumn` in the first row:

```
   \begin{longtabu} to \linewidth{@{}XX[6]X[2,c]X[1.5,c]@{}} %{X[1,c]X[4,l]X[1,c]X[l,c]}
\rowcolor{brown!50!black} 
    & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}% <-- added 
                          }{\color{white} Completed projects (Inter-institutional collaborative projects)}\\
\rowcolor{brown!50!black}    
\color{white}  Funding Agency
    & \color{white}Title of Project &  \color{white}  Amount\newline (in  \rupee)   &  \color{white} Year of sanctioned\newline(Duration)            \\
```

I like to show complete MWE however you didnt provide enough information for yours (I receive errors in compilation). If you will ad preamble and used packages and `\newcommand`s, I will complete my code.